# Try to use regexp to read nested structure

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I try to read-in following structure (python):

```
a1a:bb2b,c3cc,dd44d;e5eee:ff66,g7;h8h:i9
```

(no white spaces in-between!) to get out ideally something like

```
((a1a, (bb2b, c3cc, dd44d)),
 (e5eee, (ff66, g7)),
 (h8h, (i9)))
```

With words: 1 or more groups. Each group with one head, followed by a ":" and one or more items, separated by ",". The groups are separated by ";". Each item is alphanumeric including "_".

I tried following regex (thanks to the-fourth-bird's contribution (?:;|$)):

```
(\w+):(?:(\w+)|(?:,(\w+)(?=,))|(?:,(\w+)))+(?:;|$)
```

[as shown here](https://regex101.com/r/gS3W9O/2)

It delivers this result:

```
((a1a, bb2b, c3cc, dd44d),
 (e5eee, ff66, g7),
 (h8h, i9))
```

This is better than nothing, but not yet the exact output format as requested.

Does somebody has an idea how to tune the regex to get exactly the desired result? I'm afraid it is not possible in general to get nested groups like (bb2b, c3cc, dd44d) as it would be in (a1a, (bb2b, c3cc, dd44d)), isn't it?

Thank you in advance for any hint.
mdew

Answer (score 1):

You might use 2 capturing groups followed by matching either a semicolon or the end of the string. Then in the replacement you could use those groups combining them with the parenthesis:

```
(\w+):(\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?:;|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SmJ0g9/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VMlNkX)

**Explanation**

- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word characters in a group
- `:` Match `:`
- `(` Capture group

  - `\w+(?:,\w+)*` Match 1+ word characters followed by a group that repeats 0+ times a comma and 1+ word characters
- `)` close group
- `(?:;|$)` Match `;` or end of the string

In the replacement you could use this and them remove the trailing comma and newline

`(\1(\2)),\n`

Edit:

To get a list of tuples you could use the same regex and split the second group on a comma and create a tuple:

```
import re
text = "a1a:bb2b,c3cc,dd44d;e5eee:ff66,g7;h8h:i9"
matches = re.findall("(\w+):(\w+(?:,\w+)*)(?:;|$)", text)
matches  = list(map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(x[1].split(','))), matches))
print (matches)
```

Result:

```
[('a1a', ('bb2b', 'c3cc', 'dd44d')), ('e5eee', ('ff66', 'g7')), ('h8h', ('i9',))]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FPLjzw)

Comment: However, it's not yet perfect. The result is ('a1a', 'bb2b,c3cc,dd44d'), ('e5eee', 'ff66,g7'), ('h8h', 'i9'). Perfect would be ('a1a', ('bb2b', 'c3cc, 'dd44d')), ('e5eee', ('ff66', 'g7')), ('h8h', ('i9'))

Comment: I expanded your approach to get the structured result as expected: "(\w+):((\w+)(?:,(\w+))*)(?:;|$)". But it does not work. Result is ('a1a', 'bb2b,c3cc,dd44d', 'bb2b', ',dd44d'), ('e5eee', 'ff66,g7', 'ff66', ',g7'), ('h8h', 'i9', 'i9', ''). Do you have any idea?

Comment: @mdew Did you check the link to the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VMlNkX)? It uses re.sub instead of findall.

Comment: With repl="(\\1,(\\2)),\\n" the output looks exactly as demanded. Great. However, I tried to get a tuple to feed other python code. The re.sub() result is a pure string. Therefore, re.findall() seems to be more appropriated for this purpose.

Comment: @mdew You can use the same regex with findall. You don't know the number of groups up front, so one way is to map the comma separated items to a tuple. Try it like this https://ideone.com/FPLjzw

Comment: With this post regex processing, the result is exactly as expected. Not completely via regex, but it works. I wonder whether a 100% regex approach exists... However, thank you very much.